# Copy between S3 buckets using signed URL with boto?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I have a signed URL like this:

```
https://3RD-PARTY-BUCKET-NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/folder-name/123/filename.csv?AWSAccessKeyId=12345&Expires=1568738342&Signature=ABCDEF%3D
```

This file can be quite large, so downloading it to a server and then uploading it to S3 isn't preferable. Is there a way to directly copy it from an S3 bucket I don't own to one that I do, using boto3? I'm getting 403s for all attempts to copy the file using code like:

```
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': '3RD-PARTY-BUCKET-NAME',
    'Key': 'folder-name/123/filename.csv'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'MY-BUCKET-NAME', 'copied_file.csv.gz')
```

And I've tried appending the authentication URL parameters in a variety of ways to the key.

Comment: Why are you wanting to use a pre-signed URL? To copy an object between buckets, you need to use a **single set of credentials** that has read access on the source object and write access on the destination bucket. How are these permissions being provided? If the buckets are in different regions, the Copy command will need to be sent to the region containing the **destination bucket** (since it 'pulls' the object from the source bucket).

Comment: This is an automated export from a third party service I don't control. I'm trying to move the data into my data warehouse.

Comment: How are they providing you access to the object? Or is it publicly accessible? Are you saying that they give you a pre-signed URL and that is the only access you have over the object and its permissions?

Comment: Please see the related Question. Some things to note: The credentials being used needs write access to the destination bucket, so you'll need to add a Bucket Policy that grants the 3rd-party credentials write access to the bucket (using its ARN). It all looks rather complex!